# Why does the input function always return a string?

Tags: python

If I have such a simple code

```
varry = 1
print(type(varry))
```

it gives me - `class 'int'`

But if I have this:

```
varry = input()
print(type(varry))
```

And I type 1, it gives me `class 'str'`

Tell me please - why is it so and how should I write a program so that it defines a variable I enter correctly as int, str or float?

Comment: The `input()` function will return whatever is entered as a string.

Answer (score 3):

What you input to your program is *always* of type `str`. if you want Python to deduce the type of the input itself, use `data = eval(input())` or, for more safety:

```
import ast 
data = ast.literal_eval(input())
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But if I enter a string without "". like just an apple and not an "apple", it tells me "NameError: name 'apple' is not defined". While I enter "apple", it says class 'str'

Comment: `apple` is not a string, according to Python's syntax, while `"apple"` is.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in function [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) always returns a string, regardless of whether that string might be comprised of solely numerical characters. If you are sure the result can represent a number, then convert it:

```
varry = int(input())
```

Now the type of `varry` will be `int`, assuming this conversion doesn't raise a `ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

```
varry = int(input())

print(type(varry))
```

You have to convert it to int using int() method

Comment: The thing is - I want it to define what variables is entered. Like I dunno it in advance.

Comment: In python the type of a variable changes with assignment. If `varry="hello"` it is a string and in the next statement `varry=7` it is of type int. I'm not sure about your intent.